# Are there groups of good Skrulls?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, captain-marvel-2019

This is a question about the comics - as it relates to the Captain Marvel 2019 movie.

My understanding of the Marvel comic history (which is admittedly limited) is that Skrulls are evil conquerors. This is played heavily on throughout the movie as well.

> However, in the movie, we learn that Carol has been deceived and that the Kree she had been working for were actually evil. The Skrulls she spent the movie fighting were actually innocent refugees or something similar and apparently good, just looking for a way off the planet to find a new home.

So I'm curious if the Skrulls' society in the comics is more complex than just simple shape-shifting conquerors, if there are pockets of peaceful Skrulls disloyal to their cause, or

> is the movie adaptation just a major deviation from the comics, showing that the Skrulls are good guys all along?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206869/are-skrulls-always-evil-in-marvel-comics